# ECS - Handling components and specifically, a collision component

Tags: c++, lua

I'm working on a game in c++ and am implementing an ECS system.

1. I have a class: EntityFactory that is used to create and store an entity in a vector. An entity consists of a map of components. When a system is doing logic, should I just iterate over each entity, and then each of its components, or should I store vectors that contain references to each component created?
2. I have a component called "CollisionComponent". I'm a little confused as how to perform collision updates with the collision system. As pseudo code I was thinking this:

I'm sorry if I formatted this wrong:

```
foreach(entity)

   rect collide = getComponent<CollisionComponent>().bounds

   for(loop through every other entity with collision component)

       if(rect.intersects(otherEntity)
          //do collide logic
```

I feel like this is an inefficient way to accomplish this task.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In simple cases, a system should operate on a vector which contains all components (with system's type), each component should have ID of its entity and some internal data (such as rectangle dimensions). In non-simple cases, that shouldn't be a vector, but complex structure (such as 2D fast search tree). The idea is: a system should have all interesting components arranged in most convenient way for implementing system's logic.

Comment: tldr: you should not iterate over entities.